# Executing bash script with tilde in path

Tags: java, linux, bash, exec

I am trying to execute in linux:

```
command[0] = "~/test/bin/runScript_sh";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

But get an exception 
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
error=2, No such file or directory

Probably because it can not evaluate tilde.

What can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would replace it myself.

```
if(path.s.substring(0,1).contains("~"))
    path = path.replaceFirst("~",System.getProperty("user.home"));
```

Which gets you the string you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the user's home directory with [`System.getProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29):

```
command[0] = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/test/bin/runScript_sh";
```

Comment: Prefer replacing ~ over prepending to the command. command[0] can be user input. This way you could get `/home/username/~/test/bin/runScript.sh`

Comment: Tuim, that is not a very good idea. How does the user input a path actually containing a tilde character in that case (since it may very well be a valid path character)? Or even worse, you may give the user the impression that she can use shell semantics for the path, which may result in trying `~emil` and similar constructs. I prefer building stuff myself in these cases.

Comment: You are right, and I have updated my answer. But then again which sane person uses ~ in the path name.

Answer (score 2):

When you run a command at the shell command prompt, things like `~` expansion, quote handling, globbing, $variable expansion, input/output redirection and piping and son on are all handled by the shell ... before it asks the operating system to run the program(s) for you.

When you run a command using `Runtime.exec`, you have three choices:

- write the command without any shell "funky stuff"
- replicate what the shell would do in Java; e.g. replace leading tildes with the appropriate stuff<sup>1</sup>, or
- use exec to launch a child shell to run the command; e.g.

  ```
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/sh", "-c", "~/test/bin/runScript_sh");
  ```

  That is possibly overkill in a simple case like this.  But if you are trying to do more complicated things then a child shell can really simplify things.

---

<sup>1 - In fact fully shell compatible handing of tildes is fairly complicated.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Items such as `~` and `$HOME` are shell expansions

You have to expand these items in your program and then replace them (hint: get them from the os properties, see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) page)