# Creating Java process

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

I am trying to create a process to invoke "ls *.xml".

This code works ok:

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls build.xml");
build.xml
```

This code is wrong:

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls *.xml");
// this is the output
Cannot run program "ls *.xml": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Any idea?

Comment: what happens if you use the array form of exec: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec({"ls", "*.xml"});`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing bash script with tilde in path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273524/executing-bash-script-with-tilde-in-path)

Comment: Note: when you run exec, you are not running a shell which can understand things like `*` and `>`

Comment: Define 'is wrong'.

Answer (score 1):

That's because wildcard expansion is done by Bash shell, not by `ls` command.

If all you want to do is list files, use Files.newDirectoryStream:

```
Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(".")), p -> p.toString().endsWith(".xml")).forEach(System.out::println)
```